# WindowsForms App - How to open a website in the background and do actions?

Tags: c#, selenium, windows-forms-designer

first of all, thank you for looking at my question, it means alot. :D

A while ago i made a Selenium script in Python that logins to a website, clicks some buttons, and closes the browser.
It was very inefficient and clunky, so i tried making a more user-friendly version in a WindowsForms app in C#.

Problem is, i have no idea how to even get started, i looked online for people trying to do the same thing but i couldnt find an answer.
How do i make a Website run in the background of a WindowsForms app, Login with a username and password, Click some buttons in the Website, then close the Website?.

I have "decent" knowledge with code, so if i make any mistakes please forgive me.

**UPDATE**
I managed to get a web browser into my app by dragging it in from the toolbox, i am now looking at the microsoft docs to see how to operate it, is there a way i can block user interaction of the webbrowser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use selenium in c#. With selenium Web Driver you can do whatever you want in your code with your Website or HTML code which you download.

For more info, you can use [here](https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-c-sharp/) and also see how to implement and use it [here](https://www.javatpoint.com/selenium-csharp)
The Most common usage of selenium is in End-To-End test but you can do it what ever you want.

Here a simple example:

```
    using OpenQA.Selenium;  
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;  
using System;  
using System.Collections.Generic;  
using System.Linq;  
using System.Text;  
using System.Threading;  
using System.Threading.Tasks;  
namespace SeleniumTest  
{  
class Program  
{  
static void Main(string[] args)  
{  
Console.Write("test case started ");  
//create the reference for the browser  
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();  
// navigate to URL  
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com/");  
Thread.Sleep(2000);  
// identify the Google search text box  
IWebElement ele = driver.FindElement(By.Name("q"));  
//enter the value in the google search text box  
ele.SendKeys("javatpoint tutorials");  
Thread.Sleep(2000);  
//identify the google search button  
IWebElement ele1 = driver.FindElement(By.Name("btnK"));  
// click on the Google search button  
ele1.Click();  
Thread.Sleep(3000);  
//close the browser  
driver.Close();  
Console.Write("test case ended ");  
}  
}  
}
```

Comment: Awesome! thanks for the quick response! ill try it out

Comment: Hey! just tried it out, this is basically what my old Python project used to do.. any way i can make this run in the background instead?

Comment: @IMaestro yes you can. There is a lot of solutions that you can use in c# Dot.Net, Such as Background worker in windows app, Threading and even you can Windows Service App or HangFire Package in Web App.We have many things here :)